# Mouseout working only once

Tags: jquery, css, mouseout

http://jsfiddle.net/a08fLdte/

This is my example, if you hover over the image, it will slide some text, if you mouseout, after 2 seconds the text will slide back, and if you repeat that, it will slide in, but never slide back. Any idea why?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.image').hover(function () {
        $('.person_info').css({
            'left': '0px'
        });
    });
    $('.image').mouseout(function () {
        $(this).delay(2000).queue(function () {
            $('.person_info').css({
                'left': '-165px'
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I' had never seen lorempixel.com, Love it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `stop(true)` to the `mouseout` so that the queue is cleared before adding the slide left animation:

```
$(this).stop(true).delay(2000).queue(function () {
    $('.person_info').css({
        'left': '-165px'
    });
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/a08fLdte/1/)

Comment: It'd be nice if it didn't slide out when the mouse goes over the text. If you leave the mouse over the text, it keeps bouncing in and out

Comment: @JuanMendes if that is the behaviour the OP requires, then just change the `.image` selector to `.about_person`

Comment: This is what I asked for, thank you. And for that slide out on text, thats not a problem, thats why I'm using 2 seconds delay. :)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Just changing the selector to `.image` will not slide out when you move the mouse from the image. You can use [`relatedTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/relatedTarget) to avoid the problem http://jsfiddle.net/a08fLdte/6/

Answer (score 1):

```
$( ".image" ).mouseenter(function() {
    $('.person_info').css({
            'left': '0px'
        });
  }).mouseleave(function() {

            $('.person_info').delay(2000).css({
                'left': '-165px'
            });

  });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a08fLdte/2/)

---

[Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)

Comment: if you note the `delay` doesn't work in your fiddle!

Comment: No delay for me in your example, but Rory McCrossan solved my problem, thank you anyway. :)

Comment: @Manoz yup, I realized that but didn't want to copy now from `rory` :)